# Length of longest contiguous subarray such that the LCM of subarray is equal to the product of the elements in it

Tags: c++

[The actual problem statement](https://www.codechef.com/problems/SUBLCM)

I am facing difficulty solving this question in C++. My initial thought was to find the lowest prime factor of all the elements from 2 to 10^6 as it's the given constrain. Then, I used two-pointers and a set. My algorithm is as follows:

```
LPF = Array // LPF[i] = lowest prime factor of i precalculated

Arr = Input array // Array has elements ranging 1 to 10^6
N = Size(Arr) // N is at most 10^5

S = set
i = 0
result = 0

FOR j=0 to N-1:
    IF Arr[j] != 1 THEN: // Since 1 won't affect the result and we can always include it
        WHILE S contains LPF[Arr[j]]:
            REMOVE LPF[Arr[i]] FROM S
            i = i + 1
        ADD LPF[Arr[j]] TO S
    result = MAX(result, j-i+1)
```

Sample test cases pass. But, when I submit, it gives the wrong answer. I am just unsure whether my approach is correct or not.

My actual code:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

#pragma GCC optimize "trapv"
#define mp make_pair
#define pb push_back
#define ll long long
#define tc int testCases; cin>>testCases; while(testCases--)
#define all(v) v.begin(), v.end()

const ll P = 1000000007;
const ll SZ = 3e6;

vector<int> lpf(SZ);
void sieve() {
    lpf[1] = 1;
    for(int i=2; i<SZ; i++)
        lpf[i] = i;

    for(int i=2; i<SZ; i+=2)
        lpf[i] = 2;

    for(int i=3; (ll)i*i < SZ; i+=2) {
        if(lpf[i] == i) {
            int j = i * 2;
            while(j < SZ) {
                if(lpf[j] != 2) {
                    lpf[j] = i;
                }
                j += i;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(NULL);

    sieve();
    tc {
        int n;
        cin>>n;
        vector<int> arr(n);

        for(int i=0; i<n; i++) cin>>arr[i];

        bool lset[SZ];
        for(int i=0; i<SZ; i++) lset[i] = false;

        int i = 0;
        int res = 0;
        for(int j=0; j<n; j++) {
            if(arr[j] != 1) {
                while(lset[lpf[arr[j]]]) {
                    lset[lpf[arr[i]]] = false;
                    i++;
                }
                lset[lpf[arr[j]]] = true;
            }
            res = max(res, j-i+1);
        }

        if(res == 1) {
            cout<<-1<<"\n";
        } else cout<<res<<"\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Sample input / output:

```
Input:
3
2
7 2
4
2 2 3 4
3
2 2 4

Output:
2
2
-1
```

The code runs fine for the sample but fails for some hidden test cases which, unfortunately, CodeChef doesn't show and gives WA on submission.

Thank you!

Comment: will you be able sacrifice custom coding and use libraries like LAPACK ?

Comment: Libraries won't be available in certain competitions I guess. I am still learning competitive programming and It will be best for me to stick to the implementation aspects. For this problem though, I want to make sure if my approach is correct and if yes, are there any edge cases and all?

Comment: I need the main code, which I can directly run in my Eclipse, I tied to execute this , I get `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

Comment: But it ran in CodeChef editor without any runtime errors. It gives the wrong answer verdict on submission. :(

Comment: ok, let me try ideone

Comment: I tried, but the output it empty https://ideone.com/e3mFH0#stdin

Comment: Oh! My bad. I forgot to provide an input file. It's in the problem statement though but I will edit the question anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't consider only the lowest prime factor, you have to consider all of them. For example if you have an array `A = [10, 15]` your code will mistakenly output 2, because it thinks LCM(10,15) = 10*15 even though they share the factor 5. The rest of your two pointers approach is fine, but at each step you should remove/add *all prime factors* to the set S instead of just the lowest one.